# Example of tm use

Tags: c, tm

Can you give an example of use of `tm` (I don't know how to initialize that `struct`) where the current date is written in this format `y/m/d`?

Comment: Search for a reference for the `strftime` function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### How to use `tm` structure

1. call `time()` to get current date/time as number of seconds since 1 Jan 1970.
2. call `localtime()` to get `struct tm` pointer. If you want GMT them call `gmtime()` instead of `localtime()`.
3. Use `sprintf()` or `strftime()` to convert the struct tm to a string in any format you want.

#### Example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;
  char buffer [80];

  time ( &rawtime );
  timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );

  strftime (buffer,80,"Now it's %y/%m/%d.",timeinfo);
  puts (buffer);

  return 0;
}
```

#### Example Output

```
Now it's 12/10/24
```

#### References:

- [struct tm](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/threads/335282/struct-tm)
- [strftime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/)

Comment: And how can I write it on a file with fprintf?

Comment: @tomss use `fprintf(file_pointer, buffer);` in place of `puts(buffer);`

Comment: what is '80' in the strftime statement?

Comment: @Beginner 80 is the buffer size. From the line: `char buffer [80];`, you can see it has a size of 80. See: [strftime](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strftime.htm).

Comment: What if I want to create it for a date and time that isn't today?