# Unhandled exception at 0x00BF57F9 in Analog Clock.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, time.h

```
glRotatef((360/60) * newtime->tm_sec,0.0,0.0,1.0);
```

This is the line in which Debugger is showing my problem.
I am using `time` function.

```
struct tm *newtime;
time_t ltime;
```

Comment: your pointer (newtime) is probably invalid...

Comment: `newtime` is just a pointer, did you mean `struct tm *newtime = new newtime ();`

Comment: show us how you create newtime

Comment: How to initialize this newtime?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13658756/example-of-tm-use

Comment: I have used pointer same as this is showing.

Comment: converting time to localtime ` time(&ltime);                            
 newtime = localtime(&ltime); // Convert to local time`

Answer (score 2):

Your `newtime` variable is equal to `NULL`.  This is what the "reading location 0x00000000" part of the error is telling you.  It either needs to be initialized with a call to `new`, or changed to not use pointers (which would mean using dot `.` notation to access the member `tm_sec` on the call to glRotatef() ).

Here is a useful link for you: [An example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13658756/example-of-tm-use) of how to use the tm struct.

Comment: And also i am using this to avoid visual studio problem. This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using localtime_s instead                                                       #ifdef _MSC_VER
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif

Comment: That is a warning that incorrect use of that function will easily overflow memory causing issues.  The version they suggest has a limiter to fix that.  Go to MSDN and look up that function and there should be some sample code there as well.

Comment: yes i have solved this problem what is this when i debug my program   `-*newtime {tm_sec=??? tm_min=??? tm_hour=??? ...} tm
`` tm_sec <Unable to read memory> `

Comment: It means that either the value is within registers and cannot be read by the debugger, or newtime has yet to be assigned a value.  If it does not have a value, then reading from it will cause your crash. Look at my links for how to assign a value to newtime.

Comment: Click either on "An Example" in my answer or on the link in the comments section.

Comment: Done the same think.`time(&ltime); 
 newtime = localtime(&ltime); // Convert to local time`